# Powershell ConvertFrom-Json with arrays adds extra spaces to an array value

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

When writing a powershell script with a ConvertFrom-Json, it seems that values in arrays are converted with additional spaces when casting them to a string. The following code shows this in a small code sample:

```
$object = @"
     { 
          "object":
          {            
            "prop1": "value",
            "array":[
               { "key": "value"},
               { "key2": "valuevalue"},
               { "key3": "valuevalue"},
               { "key4": "valuevalue"},
               { "key5": "valuevalue"}
            ]
          }
     } 
"@ | ConvertFrom-Json

$object.object.prop1
$object.object.array.key

$t = $object.object.prop1
$t2= $object.object.array.key
"""$t"""
"""$t2"""
```

Output:

```
value
value
"value"
"value    "
```

Where are the extra spaces coming from in the last value? When adding more value pairs to the array, more spaces are added.

Comment: If you set $OFS to '' (null string) does it affect the output?

Comment: Yes that works idd, but why are the spaces added?

Comment: Can't say for sure, but it looks like the whole array is being cast to [string] under the covers, judging by the symptoms.  $OFS is an automatic variable that specifies a separator that will be used to separate array elements when the array is cast to [string]. The default is a single space. Setting it to null eliminated the spaces.

Comment: What is $configuration?

Comment: Thx, the original the var was called $configuration, changed it for minimal sample.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not about `ConvertFrom-Json`, it is about `$array.value`.
Starting from v3 or v4 PowerShell lets to get the specified property of array items using the dot notation.
If a property is missing then the result is null unless the strict mode is on.
In the latter case it fails.

Here is the example:

```
$array = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{key = 'value'}
    [PSCustomObject]@{key2 = 'valuevalue'}
)

$result = $array.key
$result.GetType().Name
"[$result]"
```

Output (note the result type and the extra space)

```
Object[]
[value ]
```

So the result is an array. When you cast an array to string its items are
joined with a space as the default separator (can be altered by `$OFS`).

If you run the above example in PowerShell v2 it gets `[]` because v2 does not
supports getting array item properties using the dot notation.

If you run the example with `Set-StrictMode -Version 2` then it fails with an error
*The property 'key' cannot be found on this object.* It fails in all PowerShell versions. In v2 because the array does not have the property `key`. In a later version because the second array item does not have this property.

Comment: Good catch. It's doing automatic member enumeration on a array of dissimilar single-property objects.

Answer (score -1):

It may make more sense if you write the json like this:

```
 { 
      "object":
      {            
        "prop1": "value",
        "array":[
           { "Property1": "value1"},
           { "Property1": "value2"},
           { "Property1": "value3"},
           { "Property1": "value4"},
           { "Property1": "value5"}
        ]
      }
 }
```

In other words, you get empty strings on the subsequent array members because they don't have a property named "Key."